# iOS Caching derived key during batch encryption

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, encryption

I use a combination of [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) and transformable attributes to secure some of my Core Data entities. This has worked great, however it is a pain during batch imports, where the majority of the time is spent deriving the encryption key. I have made changes so that the encryption key is derived once, cached, and reused during encryption operations.

So naturally I'm wondering if this a bad idea to cache my derived key in memory. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not really a bad idea. Actually, it may be much safer than deriving the key all the time. If there is any side channel information from the derivation process, then an attacker may get knowledge about the key.

Of course there are drawbacks. Keys in memory could be put into a page file for instance. So it would still be a good idea to overwrite the key in memory if it is not required anymore. You should obviously be very alert regarding access rights on your machine - a good hardened OS does wonders. You may also obfuscation to the key (hide it into a large block of random data, for instance) so it does not show up easily, but be aware that this only adds (very) limited protection.

Note that caching a password is (at least) as bad as caching the key - a single key derivation by an attacker would be enough to get the derived key.

Comment: Be aware that there have been many accidents regarding Direct Memory Access (DMA). Also note that gaining access to the machine may threaten the key; DDR memory can hold charge pretty long.

Comment: If this was on a computer system I would be more concerned, however since I am working with a device running iOS, the availability of the resources needed to access the information are limited. (We also make sure the device has not been jailbroken.)

Comment: iOS ***is*** a computer system. If I understand correctly, it now multi-tasks as well, so timing attacks apply. I am certainly wondering how you check that the underlying OS is not jail broken - I mean, if it is the user can hide that information. Especially in computer security, assumption is the mother...

Comment: Understanding that the iOS kernel is based off of Darwin, I believe Apple does it's due diligence to ensure that the OS is locked down and that processes are sandboxed. There are also various snippets out there for detecting if devices have been jailbroken. In the end you are right, there is no full-proof way of ensuring the system has been compromised. However, I think if you factor in everything discussed here I believe that there has been enough due diligence performed in protecting data.